# How to make a custom class to use my custom fonts dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift

I created two custom font file (regular and light font) and added it to my project and want to change my font style and the size of it dynamically. The icons are mapped to glyphs.

How would I achieve this?

```
var customFont = UIFont(name: "customregular", size: 12.0)
```

Comment: please share your code / what u've tried before.

Comment: I created an ttf. file with FontForge and mapped the glyphs and dragged and dropped the file into the project.

Comment: As @emrcftci stated. It would be good if you share some code. Did you just drag&drop the .otf files into the project? Refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app). It should give you a good overview.

Comment: @Preefix I did the things and looking for a way to call my custom fonts and change the size dynamically

Comment: please consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide reproducable copyable code, because this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform but a "we help you with your provided code "-platform

Comment: We all started somewhere but @emrcftci is right. Always share some code snippets and describe a little more what you did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We all started somewhere, so I try to answer your question.

First of all create a new public **extension**:

```
import UIKit

public extension UIFont {
   func yourCustomFont(withStyle: YourCustomStyle, ofSize: fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
      return UIFont(name: style.fontStyle(), size: fontSize)!
   }
}

public enum YourCustomStyle: String {
    case light
    case regular

    func fontStyle() -> String {
       switch self {
          case .light:
           return "customlight"
          case .regular:
           return "customregular"
       }
    }
}

public extension String {
   func mapGlyphesToIcon(name: YourFont) -> String {
      return name.rawValue
   }
}

public enum YourFont: String {
   case a = "a"
   case b = "b"
   // and so on
}
```

This way you can call **yourCustomFont** with a specific style (e.g. **light**, **regular** or what ever you have) and size. Let's say you want to assign a light font of size 20 to your button:

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.font = .yourCustomFont(withStyle: .light, ofSize: 20)
```

And now we grab the **rawValues** of our font and assign it to the **titleLabel** of our button (you can read more about **rawVales** and **enums** [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)).

We can do it that way because the button uses the custom font (above code):

```
yourButton.setTitle(.mapGlyphesToIcon(name: .a), for: .normal)
```

The **button** should display a **light** font and the title should be set to the icon which is mapped to the **glyph** ***a***.

Comment: It is possible that you also have to set the title for the **selected** state. I didn't test it but when you click on the button it could be that the you see the glyph for a moment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. When I assign the font to a button from IB it shows three dots when the view is loaded. Any ideas why?